# Is it possible to parse specific div content with COM php class and IE?

Tags: javascript, php, html, dom, com

So the question is in title. I trying to render page on server with Internet Explorer and then, after it rendered - grab content from div tag with specific Id (just a test string) and display it on page.

But all that I getting for now - IE is opening, than script throws me an error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught com_exception: <b>Source:</b> Unknown<br/><b>Description:</b> Unknown in X:\server\code.php:11 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in X:\server\code.php on line 11
```

My php code is:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$ie = new COM("InternetExplorer.Application");
$ie->Visible = true; // for debug
$handle = $ie->HWND;
$ie->Navigate2("http://testurl/test_page.html");
while ($ie->Busy) {
com_message_pump(4000);
}

$value1 = $ie->Document->body->getElementById("correct"); // <-- error is on that line!
print_r($value1);
$ie->Quit();
?>
```

I also tried to load blank page without any js scripts on it, with single 123, but It also throws same error, but at the background IE still loading Ok and page displayed.

I started to think that $ie->Document-> don't wait to fully loading of a page, cuz It takes something like, hm, 15-20 seconds to fully load all js scripts and fill div with info, but $ie->Document-> throws error after ~1 second after script started work. Is there any variants?

Also tried this:

```
$value1 = $ie->Document->innerhtml;
```

but nothing changed. What I' doing wrong?

Using php 7.4 tbh. *Its not any similar to any botting, just need some info from server-side, which can be rendered correctly only via old IE browser.*

**UPD**

Tried to change code to:

```
$ie = new COM("InternetExplorer.Application");
$ie->Visible = false; // for debug

$ie->Navigate("https://google.com");
   while ($ie->ReadyState != 4) {
       usleep(1000);
   }
$pageContent = $ie->Document->body->innerHTML;
print_r($pageContent);
```

And now error changed to:

> Fatal error: Uncaught com_exception: Error [0x80010108] The called object has been disconnected from clients.

Comment: If you want to grab some specific HTML from the page, why don't you just use a HTML/DOM parser like DOMDocument, or some similar thing? I don't see why you'd need to bother with unreliable COM components. If you just request the page with cURL, you'll get all the HTML (unless the page contains some Javascript which loads the content, of course).

Comment: @ADyson this page contains specific js code which works only in specific version of IE and I need exactly result from it as it is. Curl/DOM parser don't work with js code.

Comment: IIRC my IE 3/4/5 days and with COM, check with the ready-state of the document, it's often a timing problem. Especially as you're waiting for some JS code, it might be even more unreliable than the COM component itself, wrap in try/catch and retry with some timing (usleep() might be your friend, but mind the gap with Windows and the diverse PHP sleep-y functions).

Comment: @hakre Updated post with new information. That error seems a bit strange. Any ideas how to fix it?..